# Azure push notification to update app state

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure so forgive me if my question sounds unclear but I will try to explain the best I can.

I think it is common nowadays to need some kind of push notifications rather than pulling data in a timed interval.

So, if I have a mobile app, a web app, and a desktop app all talking to Azure, if one of these apps updates something in Azure SQL database, I would like to avoid to have to pull for this change in my other apps but instead get pushed these changes automatically to them.

I think there should be some kind of mechanism in Azure notifying the applications (whether web, mobile, desktop) about these changes.

Is there something like that?  What should I look into?

**UPDATE 1**

Assume I have an web (Angular or whatever) Azure app talking to Azure SQL database storing cars information.  This app allows me to do CRUD operations so I can add, update, delete, read cars from database.

- Database currently has info about BMW and Toyota only
- User logs into my web app and sees info about BMW and Toyota which is info
  existing in my Azure SQL database.
- User logs into my mobile app which connects to azure and **pulls** info from database and shows BMW and Toyota on screen
- User logged in web app adds new info about Honda (or deletes an existing car, or updates an existing car), info is stored in
  database and Honda shows in web app
- User logged into mobile app would now have to tap on refresh button to **pull** the latest data from database.

How can this data be automatically and immediately **pushed** to mobile app instead of having mobile app **pull** it in some interval or on tap on a Refresh button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! Azure has several messaging solutions to solve this type of problem. But without fully understanding your problem space, the semantics of your data or your overall architecture, it's hard to give precise and tailored guidance. Given that you've mentioned that some of your clients will be mobile devices, you should opt for something lightweight such as [Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview). You should also review the Service Bus and Event Hubs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services).

With whatever service you choose, I wouldn't recommend sending the actual data itself in these push notifications. Keep notifications extremely lightweight. A client, upon receiving the notification, can react by polling your backend for the actual data change.

Comment: I'd add that it could be a combination of these technologies. And you might also include SignalR for the web app.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim Added update to provide more info.  Thanks for your reply, will definitelly read the links

Comment: Notification Hubs are the way to go for your scenario. Messages have a maximum size limit of 256 bytes - 2 KB depending on the mobile platform, so your application should refetch the data from the backend once it gets notified of an update. Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-push-notifications-android-gcm and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/push-notifications/azure

Comment: @MahdiIbrahim Do I understand you correctly here?  You are saying that if my database gets inserted, modified, or deleted record, Notification Hubs (I assume there are more hubs?) will send me a notification that something has changed including what and then I have to issue *pull* got get that information?  So it is not pushing change but just notifying app to tell it to do the pull?  Also does it let app know what exactly to update?  Thanks again

Comment: ... also, from reading links you provided, I see that the notifications are delivered to the device and show in form of a popup or dialog box?  Can this notification be instead used to do targeted pull (pull *only* what changed) instead of showing a pop-up dialog?  So, if a new Jeep is added to database, I get notification and I pull *only* that Jeep rather than pulling all records or displaying a popup or notification icon?

Comment: No. It is up to you in terms of what you want to do when your mobile device receives a notification. You can make your pulls more intelligent by comparing timestamps between the data that was updated and when the device was last refreshed e.g.   
//sample android psuedo code  public class MyHandler extends NotificationsHandler {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Bundle bundle) {
        ctx = context;
        String nhMessage = bundle.getString("message");
        if (nhMessage == "carMakesUpdated"){  dataService.get("carMakes", lastPullDate); }
       
        }
    }

Comment: @RobReagan can you comment bit more on SignalR please?  Is it only for web or it works with mobile apps as well?

Comment: SignalR has a JavaScript and a .NET client. Although I have never done so, I assume you can use the .NET client in a Xamarin app. If you do, pay special attention to the SignalR connection lifetime events. When your mobile app moves to the background and is made active, the server will likely have killed your SignalR connection, thinking it's inactive. You'll need to re-establish it. I have used the SignalR JavaScript client in Ionic mobile apps and Chrome Extensions with great success.

Comment: I would caution against SignalR for this problem. The Javascript library won't work in a native app, but there is a managed SignalR service in Azure that can be used. SignalR is designed for real-time communication over sockets or a live connection (ignoring long polling). Not only is there a lot of overhead associated with this, it also chews up unnecessary bandwidth. Resources and bandwidth are real constrains on a mobile device. The OP would more than suffice with a lightweight push notification framework for the problem being solved. It's also a more correct fit.

Comment: I agree with Medhi. While you *could* use SignalR for mobile, push notifications are better. SignalR clients send very small pings to the server every X seconds to keep the connection alive.

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim What is OP?

Comment: Original Poster. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op